# Struggle with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I am struggling with mod_rewrite htaccess for at least couple of days, and still cannot figure this out.

I want to force HTTPS SSL on my site, but only from outside of the network.

I have something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.30
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

My local IP is `192.168.1.30` and it keeps correcting my adress to `https://www.mysite.com`.
In one condition it allows me to connect locally to my server. When I type `https://192.168.1.10` (my local server adress). But it keeps throwing me SSL caution which cannot be kept this way.

When I type `http://192.168.1.10` it redirects me to `https://www.mysite.com`

How to make it leave my ip alone from all the redirects?

For my logic, it should not redirect me no matter what if my `REMOTE_ADDR` is `192.168.1.30`.

Comment: Have you tried: RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.yyy\.www\.zzz, xxx.yyy.www.zzz is your World remote Internet IP supplied by your ISP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(192\.168\.|127\.0\.0\.1)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. It works in the same way my script work. If I type `http://192.168.1.10` it corrects my adress to `https://www.mysite.com`

Comment: my mistake, your solution works perfect. Didn't know somebody else added permanent redirect in *.conf of apache. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need Rewrite rules at all. Since HTTP listens on port 80 and HTTPS on port 443, you can have three different VirtualHosts.

1. First one to listen on port 80 and binds to your private ip address.
2. Second to listen on port 80 but all it does in 301 redirect to the https url
3. The last one to listen on port 443 (the HTTPS)

However, you may have to move this logic from `htaccess` file to your `.conf` file.

Since apache starts finding the matching VirtualHost in the order they are defined in the .conf file (http.conf or apache.conf as the case may be), the ordering is very important.